# Find a basis $B$ of the complex vector space of solutions of four first order differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

We need to solve the second order system of differential euqations: $$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} \begin{pmatrix} g\\
h\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 & 1 \\
1 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} g \\
h\\ \end{pmatrix}$$ We let $u_{1} = g$, $u_{2} = g'$, $u_{3} = h$, $u_{4} = h'$. Then we have a system of four first order differential equations: $$\frac{d}{dx} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_{1}\\
u_{2}\\
u_{3}\\
u_{4}\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Then we need to find a basis $B$ of the complex vector space of solutions of  these four first order differential equations. We let $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$.We first put $A$ into Jordan canonical form, denoted by $J$. We have $J = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{-1351}{780}i & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1351}{780}i & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & i\\ \end{pmatrix}$. Then this means that the four eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_{1} = \frac{-1351}{780}i$, $\lambda_{2} = \frac{1351}{780}i$, $\lambda_{3} = -i$, $\lambda_{4} = i$. Then the four corresponding eigenvectors are $v_{1} = \langle \frac{1189}{3363}i, \frac{-1079}{1762}, \frac{-1189}{3363}i, \frac{1079}{1762}\rangle$, $v_{2} = \langle \frac{-1189}{3363}i, \frac{-1079}{1762}, \frac{1189}{3363}i, \frac{1079}{1762} \rangle$, $v_{3} = \langle -\frac{1}{2}i, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{-1}{2}i, \frac{1}{2}\rangle$, $v_{4} = \langle \frac{1}{2}i, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}i, \frac{1}{2}\rangle$. Then we let $b_{1} = v_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}x}$, $b_{2} = v_{2}e^{\lambda_{2}x}$, $b_{3} = v_{3}e^{\lambda_{3}x}$, $v_{4} = v_{4}e^{\lambda_{4}x}$. Then I think that $\{b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},b_{4}\}$ is the basis of the complex vector space of these four first order differential equations. I'm wondering if my solution is correct or not. Thanks so much!

Comment: I get the same matrix $A$  as you, but the characteristic polynomial comes out $x^4 + 4x^2 +3 = (x^2 + 1)(x^2 + 3).$  I don't know where you got $\frac{1351}{780}$

Comment: @WillJagy I put the matrix into MatLab and let it tell me the eigenvalues, so maybe I used the wrong command or something

Comment: Most likely you typed some matrix element incorrectly. Please  find the characteristic polynomial  https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.charpoly.html  and compare with my version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ A=
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Demonstrating that  $i \sqrt 3$  really is an eigenvalue. I did this by hand, you really ought to do this for all four eigenvalues:  they carefully set this up to make hand work feasible.

$$ A - i \sqrt 3 \,  I  \;=
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 - i \sqrt 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-2 & - i \sqrt 3  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - i \sqrt 3 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & -2 & -i \sqrt3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

I did not bother to row reduce, this one is already in good shape for back substitution. I chose the fourth element to be $3$  to avoid fractions.  So, to begin, call this column vector $V_4$  as I plan to use it as the fourth column in my square matrix $P$   of eigenvectors.
To begin,

$$  V_4
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
p \\ 
q \\ 
r \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Write the **third row** of $A - i \sqrt 3  I$  as $-i \sqrt 3 r + 3 = 0,$  multiply through by $i \sqrt 3$  to reach $3r + 3 i \sqrt 3 = 0$  or $r + i \sqrt 3 = 0,$  so $r = - i \sqrt 3.$  We now know

$$  V_4
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
p \\ 
q \\ 
-i \sqrt 3 \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Write the **fourth** row of $A - i \sqrt 3  I$  as
$ p = 2(-i \sqrt 3) + 3 (i \sqrt 3)  = i \sqrt 3.$  Thus

$$  V_4
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
i \sqrt 3 \\ 
q \\ 
-i \sqrt 3 \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Write the **first** row of $A - i \sqrt 3  I$  as
$ 3 +q=0.$  Thus  $q = -3$ and

$$  V_4
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
i \sqrt 3 \\ 
-3 \\ 
-i \sqrt 3 \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

To check, verify with the original matrix $A$  that $A V_4 = i \sqrt 3 V_4.$
First
$$ i \sqrt 3   V_4
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
-3 \\ 
-3 i \sqrt 3 \\ 
3 \\ 
3 i \sqrt 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Finally
$$ A V_4=
 \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
 \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
i \sqrt 3 \\ 
-3 \\ 
-i \sqrt 3 \\ 
3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

so that
$$ A   V_4
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{r} 
-3 \\ 
-3 i \sqrt 3 \\ 
3 \\ 
3 i \sqrt 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

You really should do all of this for the remaining eigenvalues $i, -i, -i \sqrt 3$ including the checking. This problem was set up carefully so that hand calculations would work out in a reasonable time; the effort teaches you how things ought to appear and firms up the concepts.